# Why do I get a Content Encoding Error?

Tags: admin, sysadmin

Using Firefox on a Mac generates erratic and inconsistent error screens that say "Content Encoding Error". Sometimes reloading the page solves it, sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an unexpected odyssey.

1. This error was misleading, and actually indicated that some of the page elements were being returned with 0 bytes.
2. Those elements were civicrm php urls, and most of the errors we noticed where from a 4.7 installation.
3. There were unhelpful messages in the php error log until I turned on 'catch_workers_output=yes' in the php-fpm.d/www.conf file.
4. The detailed error 'WARNING: [pool php56u] child 31883 said into stderr: "zend_mm_heap corrupted"' led me to https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65590
5. A suggestion in that thread "opcache.fast_shutdown=0" appears to have resolved the issue.